# React hooks, how to fire some logic once when component unmounts

Tags: reactjs

I'm playing with hooks now. My code looks like that:

```
    import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

import storage from '../../utils/localStorage';

const STORAGE_VIDEOS_DATA_KEY = 'VIDEOS_DATA';

const VideoItem = () => {
  const [ playingStatus, setPlayingStatus ] = useState(false);
  const [ videoId ] = useState(318298217);
  const [ videoProgress, setVideoProgress ] = useState(0);
  const player = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      'beforeunload',
      saveStateToLocalStorage
    );

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(
        'beforeunload',
        saveStateToLocalStorage
      );
      saveStateToLocalStorage(); // this needs to be fired only once when component onmounts but clearing effect is done every time videoProgress changes
    };
  }, [videoProgress]);

  const onVideoEnd = () => {
    console.log('backend call - video end status');
  };

  const seekToPoint = () => {
    const videosData = storage.hasKey(STORAGE_VIDEOS_DATA_KEY) &&
      JSON.parse(storage.getItem(STORAGE_VIDEOS_DATA_KEY));
    const toReturnVideoPoint = videosData[videoId] || 0;

    player.current.seekTo(Number(toReturnVideoPoint));
  };

  const saveStateToLocalStorage = () => {
    const videosPlayedDuration = {
      [videoId]: videoProgress,
    };

    storage.setItem(STORAGE_VIDEOS_DATA_KEY, JSON.stringify(videosPlayedDuration));
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ReactPlayer
        ref={player}
        playing={playingStatus}
        url={`https://player.vimeo.com/video/${videoId}`}
        onPause={() => {
          saveStateToLocalStorage();
          setPlayingStatus(false);
        }}
        onEnded={onVideoEnd}
        onProgress={progress => setVideoProgress(progress.playedSeconds)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => {
        seekToPoint();
        setPlayingStatus(true);
      }}
      >
        GO BACK TO THE PREVIOUS POINT
      </button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default VideoItem;
```

I want to clear my effect only when component unmounts, not everytime component gets rerendered when videoProgress piece of state changes. I could just use empty array instead of `[ videoProgress ]` but then `videoProgress` in method `saveStateToLocalStorage` won't get updated and `onPause` method won't cause a proper saving to localStorage (it will save 0). Is there a way to do that with hooks and not using class component with `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle?

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand how `useEffect` works.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // your code
    return () => {
      // your clearup code 
    };
  }, [videoProgress]); // => This is the key point. It's called dependency
```

Whenever the dependency gets changed, react re-run the `useEffect`. Your `videoProgress` value gets changes after time interval (may be after 1 sec, I don't know). That's why react re-run the useEffect.

You can do this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // your code
    return () => {
      // your clearup code. =>> This block will work as componentWillUnmount
    };
  }, []); // => No Dependency
```

Or you can add dependency of your video id (as per your requirements).

---

## One Handy example

```
useEffect(() => {
    // This block (before the return) will act as componentDidMount
    return () => {
      // This block will work as componentWillUnmount
    };
  }, []); // => beacase of No Dependency
```

One Side note: You can have multiple useEffect.

Comment: To add to this, you can have multiple `useEffect` functions, so you can have one that runs once via passing an empty array and another that does stuff that should be done when `videoProgress` has changed.

Comment: Updated Anwser with few more details

Comment: Ok, I get it, but when I use empty array [ ] then my component is not updated and in saveStateToLocalStorage method it saves the initial value of 0.